# Using dynamic sessionId and token in OpenTok-Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, opentok

I want try the aullman example OpenTok-Angular: https://github.com/aullman/OpenTok-Angular

But, in the second step (Replace your apiKey, sessionId and token in the demo.html file), I want replace with my sessionId and token generated dynamically by OpenTok SDK Node.js (that I've done already in app.js)

How I could do it?

**PS: MY app.js FILE that render in view apiKey, sessionId and Token:**

```js
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var newSession = require('./credentialsPromise').newSession(); //obtains the promise with sessionId and token generated dynamically

var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//Init the app
init();


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  //Promise
  newSession.then(function(req){
    //fullfilled
    var obj = req;
    //Render in view
    res.render('index.ejs', {
      apiKey: obj.apiKey,
      sessionId: obj.sessionId,
      token: obj.tokenId
    });
  }, function(reject){ //rejected
    console.log("Error, cannot use promise");
  });
});

function init() {
  app.listen(server_port, function() {
    console.log('App is running in localhost:' + server_port);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the demo.html to index.ejs and store it in views folder (modifying the paths, obviously).

Then, I've changed my apiKey, sessionId and token by values that returns app.js, as follow:

```js
  angular.module('demo', ['opentok'])
            .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'OTSession', 'apiKey', 'sessionId', 'token', function($scope, OTSession, apiKey, sessionId, token) {
                OTSession.init(apiKey, sessionId, token);
                $scope.streams = OTSession.streams;
            }]).value({
                apiKey: '<%= apiKey %>',
                sessionId: '<%= sessionId %>',
                token: '<%= token %>'
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Rest API using node js and call that api from your angular js page. After getting successful response from node js, get that session id and token in variable and pass in your angular js method.

How to create Rest API.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

Comment: I've created already that Rest API, generating sessionId and token dynamically. I want to know where I should put in, in views or in angular controller?